# How do I log in with my connection string into my MongoDB cluster?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

For example my email is bobsmith123@email.com and my password is "password" or url encoded is "p%40ssword" (this is not my actual password). Would my connection string be:

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://bobsmith123:p@40ssword@cluster0.mpnik7h.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0";
```

or

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://bobsmith123%40email.com:p%40ssword@cluster0.mpnik7h.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0";
```

I am consistently getting this error (my password is correct when I log into Mongodb cloud, I checked):

```
MongoServerError: bad auth : authentication failed     at Connection.sendCommand (C:\Users\User\Desktop\project\project-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:281:27)     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)     at async Connection.command (C:\Users\User\Desktop\project\project-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:304:26)     at async continueScramConversation (C:\Users\User\Desktop\project\project-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\auth\scram.js:131:15)     at async executeScram (C:\Users\User\Desktop\project\project-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\auth\scram.js:80:5)     at async performInitialHandshake (C:\Users\User\Desktop\project\project-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:101:13)     at async connect (C:\Users\User\Desktop\project\project-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:19:9) {   errorResponse: {     ok: 0,     errmsg: 'bad auth : authentication failed',     code: 8000,     codeName: 'AtlasError'   },   ok: 0,   code: 8000,   codeName: 'AtlasError',   connectionGeneration: 0,   [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(2) { 'HandshakeError', 'ResetPool' } }
```

for reference this is the database code:

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const ServerApiVersion = require("mongodb").ServerApiVersion;
//uri is kept secret from users
const uri = require('./url.js').uri;
//const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
console.log(uri);
const client = new MongoClient(uri, 
    {ServerApi: 
        {
            version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
            strict: true,
            deprecationErrors: true
        }
    }
);
console.log(client);
let db;
async function run() {
    try{
        await client.connect();
        await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
        console.log("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!");
        //db = client.db("Cluster0");
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }finally{
        await client.close();
    }
};
run();
module.exports = {db}
```

I was expecting to log in with any one of those two uri statements but I failed.

Comment: To save yourself the hassle of workarounds just don't use the `@` symbol within a password. Change your password to something else. Your first connection string format is fine (without the `@` of course).